# DropDown values lost when FileUpload.IsInFileUploadPostBack

Tags: c#

i'm working on a web project. I have a dropdown and i need the selectedvalue for uploading a file using asp:AjaxFileUpload.

Issue: when uploading a file, dropdown values are lost and the selectedvalue will be blank. I don't want to use a Session variable because if I open the same page in two tabs with different dropdown.selectedvalue, the other page might get the wrong session variable. Please help me find another way of getting the dropdown.selectedvalue when uploading a file,

your help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

Enclose your DropDownList in an asp UpdatePanel as below:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="someid" runat="server>
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="yourdropdownlist" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
</ContentTemplate>
</UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: thank you Rohit,

all my controls are inside an update panel, 

i've also tried using a hiddenfield outside the update panel just to check if the value will not be affected when uploading, but still the same problem

Comment: Try storing the selected value in a static string varaible.
PS: The file uploader should be kept outside the update panel.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your page is posting back each time.

Set `AutoPostBack='false'` and use `Page.IsPostback` property while populating and dealing with drop down box.

**MSDN For IsPostBack:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx

Hope Its Helpful.

Comment: You will have to implement the programming logic in this case, you will have to take the selected values in one variable and then populate the values and then again make selected the value from listbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use update panel and inside that put your dropdown, file upload control etc..
in your code behind on `Page_Load` check below condition and bind data.

```
if (!IsPostBack && !IsCallback && !AjaxFileUpload1.IsInFileUploadPostBack) // Need to prevent normal stuff on ajaxFileUpload PostBack
{
     // bind drop down , gridview etc..
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply..

this is part of my code for pageload

if (!Page.IsPostBack && !fileAttach.IsInFileUploadPostBack)
{
   PopulateDropdown
}
else //system will go here when uploading
{
   //dropdown.items.count = 0;
   //how can i bind values to dropdown without losing the previously selectedvalue
}